# Baffling Exception From Django 2.0 Admin Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is a weird (for me) debugging issue. I have a Django 2.0 application with three apps - app1, app2, and app3. app1 was working a long time ago, as well as app2 and app3. At this point, I am only using the admin interface for all three apps. I was doing some work in app3 to optimize some code. I completed that and was running some quick tests on app1, and it blows up. I can access the main admin page for all the models in app1, but when I click on the change page I get this error

```
Template error:
In template /home/mark/python-projects/memorabilia-JSON/memorabilia/templates/admin/memorabilia/change_form.html, error at line 14
   Could not parse the remainder: '>' from ''</table'>'
   4 : 
   5 : {% for fieldset in adminform %}
   6 :   {% cycle '<table border=0 width=100%>' ' ' %}
   7 :   {% cycle '<tr>' ' ' %}
   8 :   {% cycle '<td width =50%’ ‘td width =50%>' ' ' %}
   9 :   
   10 :   {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
   11 :   
   12 :   {% cycle '</td>' '</td>' ' ' %}
   13 :   {% cycle  '</tr>' ' '%}
   14 :    {% cycle  '</table'> ' ' %} 
   15 :   
   16 : {% endfor %}
   17 : {% endblock %}
   18 : 
   19 : 

Traceback:

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_template
  63.             return select_template(template, using=self.using)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in select_template
  42.                 return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in get_template
  34.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in get_template
  144.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  126.                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py" in get_template
  30.                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  160.         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_nodelist
  198.             return parser.parse()

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  483.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  481.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in do_extends
  290.     nodelist = parser.parse()

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  483.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  481.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in do_block
  233.     nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  483.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  481.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in do_for
  815.     nodelist_loop = parser.parse(('empty', 'endfor',))

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  483.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  481.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in cycle
  628.         values = [parser.compile_filter(arg) for arg in args[1:]]

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in <listcomp>
  628.         values = [parser.compile_filter(arg) for arg in args[1:]]

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_filter
  568.         return FilterExpression(token, self)

File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/memorabilia-JSON/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  668.                                       "from '%s'" % (token[upto:], token))

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/memorabilia/collection/1/change/
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '>' from ''</table'>'
```

None of the admin pages for app2 and app3 have this error - they work just fine. I have never touched the admin templates for any of the apps. I tried doing a diff between the admin.py and all the .py files for app1 with an earlier version, and there are no differences. I also looked at differences in the .py files from an earlier version of app2 and app3, and the only changes were the ones that I made, and none of them throw and error when I use the admin change form for the models in those apps.

I am at a loss as how to track down the source of this bug since it is coming from the bowels of Django code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your template. You have a quote in the wrong place:

```
14 :    {% cycle  '</table'> ' ' %}
```

Should be:

```
14 :    {% cycle  '</table>' ' ' %}
```

This is in `memorabilia-JSON/memorabilia/templates/admin/memorabilia/change_form.html` according to the traceback.

Comment: Doh! I forgot I made some template changes a looooong time ago. I thought that was a template generated by django. My apologies for asking a really bad question.